I am citing from a paper which confused the word "affective" and "affectionate", what should I do?
I understand that with minor spelling mistakes you use [sic] or just [brackets]. However, in this case, I think the author accidentally wrote the wrong word.
It looks odd to write affect[ionat]e and if I just write [sic] it is not obvious which word he intended to use.
Should I use a footnote instead?
I am using APA style.
Thanks!

It may look odd, but "affect[ionat]e" would be pretty standard if you do have to directly quote that section, though paraphrasing it instead of directly quoting it might be better.

Is it necessary to quote? Most academic citations, at least in fields I am familiar with, are not quotes. And are you quite certain that they've made a mistake? "Affective" is quite a common word in, say, psychology.

@WhatTheDuck thank you for this idea

@BryanKrause Hi, I am referencing a model called the Gender Role Conflict Scale, and one of its patterns was called "Restrictive Affectionate..." by its original author. The author whose paper I read has called it "Restrictive Affective...". I am not sure how else to refer to this term/name of a pattern. Thank you for your help.

@Ali I'd say that's sufficient to be quite certain it's a mistake. But why is it necessary to quote them?

Hello, thank you. I feel I ought to quote them, by putting "" around the term Restrictive Affectionate Behaviour, as it is a specific term that the original author came up with, it is not a widely known one. Have I understood what "quoting" means correctly? Is there perhaps another way of making it clear the term is not mine? Thank you for your prior explanation which makes me reflect.

You don't generally need to use quotation marks for terminology, even if the terminology comes from somewhere else, just make sure it's clear where it comes from. But in any case, in this scenario it's not coming from the source that got it "wrong", you would not want to quote them for coming up with that phrase because it's not their scale.

I would use - "affective (sic: affectionate)"

I don't think this makes it clear which one they wrote and which one is correct

The fact that the words "sic: affectionate" are in parentheses tells the reader that they have been added. And, in any event, it should be clear from context that "affective" is original and incorrect and "affectionate" corrects it.

Sic usually appears on its own in brackets after the word that appears, not with that word inside the brackets and separated by a colon. So it seems unclear to me. And it will only be clear from context if the reader knows what the two words mean, which might not be the case.

If that's too difficult for an average reader. how about "affective (sic, i.e., affectionate)"?

That is not clear either. This would be clear: affective (sic; the correct word is affectionate).

Well, I think that most readers would easily understand both suggestions. OTOH, maybe I'm giving readers too much credit. Perhaps someone else can chime in. –
